# Parametric curve on data points - Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, parametric-equations

I'm new to gnuplot and after some research, it looks like nobody already raised this question.
I have a data file with x,y points :

x1, y1

x2, y2

..

and I want to plot a parametric curve on each of these points. The parametric curves might be different for each point, and parameters of those curves might be function of the points coordinates. Is there an easy way to store the variables of each of these points ?
Thanks

Comment: Huh? I don't really get what you expect from the script. Can you show some sample input and be specific in what you expect? How can one point result in a parametric curve?

Comment: These points result from experimental measurements, and each of these measurements has a specific resolution (astronomic observations). These resolution can be spherical (when observing with one antenna) or ellipsoidal (when observing with several antennas, interferometric observations). The x,y data represent the position of my measurements, and I would like to draw the resolution on each of these points, so circle or ellipsoid. That's why I'm using parametric curves..

Comment: You can use the `circles` or `ellipse` plotting styles, see http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.6/circles.html